# How to query an array of objects to match any of the provided values?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, object

| variation_id | Combo_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"variation_id":"420","quantity":1,"unit_id":"12"}, {"variation_id":"421","quantity":1,"unit_id":"12"}] |
| 2 | [{"variation_id":"422","quantity":1,"unit_id":"12"},{"variation_id":"430","quantity":1,"unit_id":"12"}] |

How to check if I have variable_id like 420 and I want to check that variable_id is in the Combo_ids column ( variation_table) ?

```
SELECT * FROM variation_table v WHERE v.Combo_ids LIKE '%"variation_id":"420"%';
```

This one work.

Is there any other solution to filter like this array Objects ??

Finally I found a solution. Using JSON_TABLE I can Do like this

```
SELECT variation_combo.*, v.Combo_ids, v.id FROM variation_table v ,
     JSON_TABLE( v.Combo_ids , '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                variation_id VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.variation_id',
                quantity float(25) PATH '$.quantity')
                ) variation_combo
                WHERE variation_combo.variation_id = 420;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? Also, why not normalize your database, such that you don't have to store "objects" in a column?

Comment: You may want to have a look at JSON data types in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: JSON_TABLE https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973
This one help